# Array modifier for light

Tags: modifiers, light

I want to create an array of lights contained within a space.
There appears to be no way to apply an Array Modifier to a light object -- why not?
Is there a non-Python way perhaps to create and space light objects without Python?

Comment: Fairly obscure, but it works